# How to invoke yarn command in docker's jenkins?

Tags: docker

When I install yarn using this command in CentOS terminal:

```
sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo
# Install yarn    
yum install -y yarn
```

The yarn command run perfectly in terminal. But when the run the yarn install command in Docker's Jenkins(after docker's jenkins chekcout the project source code,compile react project),this is my build script:

```
yarn install 
yarn build
```

it throw this error:

```
/bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins3735067167187767767.sh
+ yarn install
/tmp/jenkins3735067167187767767.sh: 2: /tmp/jenkins3735067167187767767.sh: yarn: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

When I don't using docker,I know it runs as user jenkins,but now I could not switch to user jenkins because it does not have a jenkins user.How to fix it?

Docker version 1.13.1, build 07f3374/1.13.1
Node version:v10.15.3
yarn version:v1.15.2

Comment: have you added the yarn repository so you can install it using yum ?

Comment: yes,i added the yarn repo.@MostafaHussein

Comment: can you add the steps that you are using so we can help ?

Comment: I add the detail information,is this what you need?@MostafaHussein

Comment: Your question does not explain how do you install yarn in docker, you said you install it inside the host itself but not docker, am i right ?

Comment: I've tried to install into docker.But it doest not have yum command in docker.I login docker using this command:docker exec -it 4ed55631985b bash@MostafaHussein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your host is isolated from the docker container, so whatever you need to install you have to install inside the container itself not on the actual host. In case you are using an ubuntu image you need to do the following steps inside your container or inside your Dockerfile if you are building your own image. Make sure to use the root user for these steps:

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
apt update
apt install yarn
```

If you are just getting started with docker I suggest that you take a look at the following tutorial to get a better view about how it works: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

Comment: I use npm now,yarn aways have a problem.But I know docker should install component  independent from your answer.

Comment: Yes exactly, you are correct, any required packages should be inside the container itself